# How to have a directive having templateUrl as null or undefined or empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement a directive which is generalized for dropdown menus.
I usually pass the templateUrl of the menus which have a large template. 
But there are small menus like 3 "li"(s) in a "ul" tag. 
I don't want to make a separate template of them to be called using templateUrl, I just want to implement the functionality using the html that's inside the element on which the directive is implemented.

```
return {
        restrict : 'A',
        templateUrl: function(element,attrs){
            return (attrs.templateUrl)? attrs.templateUrl : null;
        },
        scope:"",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
}
```

This is what I'm doing but getting error as it wants to load the template. What's the work around here?

**Aim = To render template if passed as templateUrl, or to just use the elements within the directive's element if templateUrl isn't passed as an attribute**

Answer (score 1):

I'm making my own framework and I ran into the same situation as you. 
So I wrote a module that performs dynamic template urls. If no element or default `templateUrl` is defined, it stores the inner content of the element as string within the `$templateCache` service named with a random generated key, then if you set it dynamically as the directive's `templateUrl` property, the content of its element will be the same as you wrote initially.
I don't know if this is a perfect solution but is enough for me:

The module (sorry, I cannot host it, Information Security of my work blocks all)

```
(function(){
    var moduleName = "templateManager",
        serviceName = "TemplateManager",
        NAMES = {
            ATTR_NAME: "templateUrl",
            TEMPLATE: "templateUrl",
        };

    angular.module(moduleName, [])
    .provider(
        serviceName,
        function(){
            function randomSelector(){
                var str = ""; 
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    str += String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (91-65) + 65));
                return str + "_" + String(Math.random().toFixed(5)).split(".")[1];
            }

            this.$get = ["$templateCache",function($templateCache){
                var serv = {};
                //Private
                function noTpl(contents){
                    var selector = randomSelector();
                    $templateCache.put(selector, contents);
                    return selector;
                }
                //Public
                serv[NAMES.TEMPLATE] = function(templateUrl){

                    return function(tElem, tAttrs){
                        var defaultTpl = angular.isDefined(templateUrl) ? (angular.isFunction(templateUrl) ? templateUrl.apply(this,arguments) : templateUrl) : undefined,
                            elementTpl = angular.isDefined(tAttrs[NAMES.ATTR_NAME]) ? tAttrs[NAMES.ATTR_NAME] : undefined;

                        return elementTpl || defaultTpl || noTpl(tElem.html());
                    }
                }
                return serv;
            }]
        }
    );
})();
```

An use case

```
<script>
angular.module("test",["templateManager"])
.directive(
    "dynTpl",
    ["TemplateManager",function(TemplateManager){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: TemplateManager.getTemplateUrl(
                function(tElem, tAttrs){ //only for testing
                    if(tAttrs.testTpl === "default")
                        return "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test.asp";
                    return undefined; 
                }),
        }
    }]
)
</script>
<body ng-app="test">
<dyn-tpl><p>Content!!</p></dyn-tpl> <!-- Should show: Content!! -->
<dyn-tpl test-tpl="default"><p>Content!!</p></dyn-tpl> <!-- Should show: This is some text from an external ASP file. -->
<dyn-tpl template-url="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_test_post.asp"><p>Content!!</p></dyn-tpl> <!-- Should show: Dear . Hope you live well in . -->
</body>
```

As you can see, this module always uses a templateUrl defined by default, by the user or from the cache that contains the original content.

I Hope I helped and sorry if my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this site provides the solution, you should get yourself the html and then use the `$compile()` function:
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

```
app.directive('contentItem', function ($compile) {

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        if (scope.contentTemplate !== undefined){
            element.html(getTemplate(scope.contentTemplate)).show();
        }
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

});
```

Comment: That's not what I want actually. I it shouldn't try to load the html from url if I didn't pass the templateUrl as an attribute in the directive.

Comment: probably just checking if the attribute is not undefined should do it

Comment: lol what makes you think I didn't do that? 

Here's the usecase: 
If i pass a url as templateUrl attribute, the templateUrl property of directive fetches the html from it
If I don't pass the url, it fetches undefined and gives error. I want the directive NOT to get data if I didn't pass a url.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to use the templateCache, and the local template variable ?
when you declare a templateURL, the $templateCache is used before doing any http request
if it returns nothing, you can set an empty template, or whatever.

when declaring your directive you can do:

```
angular.module('<yourmodule>').directive('<yourdirective',[$templateCache, function($templateCache){
   var myTemplate = $templateCache.get('anURL') || "";
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      //other declarations
      template: myTemplate
   }
}]);
```

Hope this helps.